# How to handle duplicates in a StringList with dupError

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

This is an attempt to add filenames to a stringlist.  If a duplicate filename is added to the list
raise an exception and remove the original file from the list.  It is my understanding from the help file that if a duplicate file is found the index of the existing entry will be returned which can then be used to delete the existing entry.

The problem with this code is that when a duplicate is found, the code in the EListError Exception is not executed.

My question is, if a duplicate filename exists how do you remove the original filename from the list?
In essence if a duplicate is detected when it is added I want to eliminate the original file from the list.  Unfortunately the code in the exception trap does not execute when a duplicate file is added to the list.

```
{ Create a list of files to delete }
iListOfImagesToDelete := TStringList.Create;
try
  { Get a ListOfFiles in each collection }
  iCollectionList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    iListOfImagesToDelete.Duplicates := dupError;
    iListOfImagesToDelete.Sorted := True;
    { Add filenames to a stringlist with Duplicates set to dupError and Sorted set to True }
    iFileCount := iCollectionList.Count;
    for j := 0 to iFileCount - 1 do
      begin
        iFilename := iCollectionList[j];
        if FileExists(iFilename) then
        begin
           try
             iFileIndex := iListOfImagesToDelete.Add(iFilename);
           except
           { file exists in the list }
           on EListError do
           begin
              ShowMessage(ExtractFilename(ifilename) + ' exists.');
              { Remove the original duplicate file from the list }
              iListOfImagesToDelete.Delete(iFileIndex);
           end;
         end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
     iCollectionList.Free;
  end;
finally
    iListOfImagesToDelete.Free;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a duplicate entry is detected, `dupError` raises an `EStringListError` exception.  The index of the existing item is specified in the error message, but is not otherwise exposed.  So you would have to either parse the error message to discover the index, or stop using `dupError` and use `IndexOf()` instead:

```
{ Create a list of files to delete }
iListOfImagesToDelete := TStringList.Create;
try
  { Get a ListOfFiles in each collection }
  iCollectionList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    iListOfImagesToDelete.Sorted := True;
    { Add filenames to a stringlist }
    iFileCount := iCollectionList.Count;
    for j := 0 to iFileCount - 1 do
    begin
      iFilename := iCollectionList[j];
      if FileExists(iFilename) then
      begin
        iFileIndex := iListOfImagesToDelete.IndexOf(iFilename);
        if iFileIndex = -1 then
        begin
          { file does not exist in the list }
          iListOfImagesToDelete.Add(iFilename);
        end else
        begin
          { file exists in the list }
          ShowMessage(ExtractFileName(iFilename) + ' exists.');
          { Remove the original duplicate file from the list }
          iListOfImagesToDelete.Delete(iFileIndex);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    iCollectionList.Free;
  end;
finally
  iListOfImagesToDelete.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

The error raised is `EStringListError`. You are looking for `EListError`.

Comment: Thanks Uwe... but now iFileIndex := iListOfImagesToDelete.Add(iFilename); is returning 1 when it should be returning 0.  Any ideas?